# Rails 4 and Mongoid nested has_one relationship not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm having a problem with a has_one relationship inside an embedded relationship. The relationship is recipe embeds_many ilist, ilist has_one ingredient. I am using a single form for this but when I submit the ingredient is not stored in the ilist.

recipe model

```
class Recipe
 include Mongoid::Document
 .
 .
   embeds_many :ilists
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ilists,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if     => :all_blank,
    autosave: true
end
```

recipe controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /recipes
  # GET /recipes.json
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  # GET /recipes/1
  # GET /recipes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /recipes/new
  def new
     @recipe = Recipe.new
     3.times { @recipe.ilists.build }
  end

  # GET /recipes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /recipes
  # POST /recipes.json
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully     created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  # DELETE /recipes/1
  # DELETE /recipes/1.json
  def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to recipes_url, notice: 'Recipe was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_recipe
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :photo, :type, :preptime, :serves, :description, :calories, :protien, :Fat, :cholesterol, :sodium, :potassium, :carbohydrate, :fiber, :sugar, :calcium, :iron, :zinc, :copper, :choline, :fluoride, :folate, :magnesium, :manganese, :phosphorus, :potassium, :selenium, :vitaminA, :vitaminB1, :vitaminB2, :vitaminB3, :vitaminB4, :vitaminB5, :vitaminB6, :vitaminB12, :vitaminC, :vitaminD, :vitaminE, :vitaminK, :vegetarian, :lactovegetarian, :vegan, :halal, :pescetarian, :glutenfree, :alcohol, ilists_attributes: [ :ingrediant, :quantity])
    end
end
```

ilist model

```
class Ilist
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :quantity, type: Integer

  has_one :ingrediant
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingrediant,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if     => :all_blank,
    autosave: true
  embedded_in :recipe, inverse_of: :ilists
end
**ilist controller params**
params.require(:ilist).permit( ingrediant_attribute: [ :name, :calories,..], :quantity)
```

Ingrediant model(I know I spelled ingredient wrong)

```
class Ingrediant
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 field :calories, type: BigDecimal
 field :protien, type: BigDecimal
 .
 .

 belongs_to :ilist
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for @recipe, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
.
<%= f.fields_for :ilists do |builder| %>
  <tr>

  <td><%= builder.collection_select :ingrediant, Ingrediant.all, :id, :name, {} %></td>
  <td><%= builder.text_field :quantity %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In the HTTP post in the console I can see the recipe post along with

```
"..,ilists_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ingrediant"=>"56ccc8b7de301b1904488361", "quantity"=>"100"},..
```

56ccc8b7de301b1904488361 is the _id for chicken breast in the ingredient database, i don't want just the _id i need to be able to query the whole ingredient.

The idea is that each ilist contains all the information from an ingredient as well as the quantity so I can calculate the nutritional values of the recipe through the controller on create(not sure how to do this but one problem at a time).

Answer (score 0):

You have embedded a ilist within a recipe that has one ingrediant, however you have not embedded ingrediants with the ilist, therefore you have two document collections, recipes & ingrediants that are related via embedded ilists. To get the ingrediant, you would need to call recipe.ilist.ingrediant to return the document. As it is a separate, but related document mongoid will only store the _id within the ilist.

As a side note, I would recommend for maintenance reasons updating the spelling of your collections if you have the opportunity.